# How to set the font in an Org-mode buffer?

Tags: org-mode, fonts

Is there a simple way to set the font used when viewing an `.org` file, so that it applies to that file every time you open it? I'm imagining something with the properties, like the imagined example below.

I'm sure there is a way to do this with Emacs Lisp, adding to `org-mode-hook` and programmatically setting the `face` text property or something like that. But before I do that, I wanted to check if there was a simple way, without writing Lisp code.

I understand that typical users of Emacs do not care about this kind of thing. Like most people, I use it primarily as a code editor, but sometimes I care what my text looks like on screen and want to play with different fonts.

```
#+FONT Helvetica Neue, 14pt

* Uno
* Dos
* Tres
```

Comment: Do you want to affect only a particular file or all `*.org` files, that is, all files opened in Org mode? Guessing the latter, I edited the question slightly. If I'm wrong, feel free to edit it again or roll back my edit.

Comment: I want to set it just for a particular file. I'd like to have different .org files with different fonts, just like I can do with a standard word processor application. I'm not sure what a "buffer-mode" property is, so I'm not sure if your edit fits my meaning or not. It sounds like it does. (?) I get sick of staring at the same font. Sometimes I like to pick a new font because I like the way it looks, and it helps me think. But I do this on a per-file basis; it depends on the content.

Comment: "... just like I can do with a standard word processor application..." - Emacs is not a word processor and certainly not a "standard" one, so if you insist on treating it like one, you are going to be disappointed. In particular, there is no `#+FONT: ` facility in Org mode and it is extremely unlikely that something like it will ever be implemented.

Comment: OK, sorry for my edit then. Please roll it back or edit it further, to express what you meant. I made a (wrong) guess that you wanted to do the same for all *.org files.

Comment: Yes, I use Emacs all day, for everything from C++ to Emacs Lisp to org mode. I know it's a unique and awesome system, not a word processor. I said that just to describe what I want to do. If there is no 'easy' feature, I'm sure there is a way to write something in lisp and add it to `org-mode-hook`.

Comment: See e.g. https://zzamboni.org/post/beautifying-org-mode-in-emacs/ for some possible directions.

Answer (score 2):

Buffer local faces (including the font family) can be set using the function `face-remap-add-relative`, which sets the variable `face-remapping-alist`.  `org-mode` files can have file-local settings such as placing a snippet like this at the top of the file:

```
# -*- eval: (face-remap-add-relative 'default '(:family "Courier" :height 160 :background "yellow")); -*-
```

**OR**

```
# -*- eval: (face-remap-add-relative 'default '(:family "Monospace" :height 160 :background "yellow")); -*-
```

**NOTE**:  Emacs expects `:family`, not `:font`, in this particular example.

See the manual for other file-local settings:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html